# COPY to Postgres using glob result in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, glob

I'm trying to create a python script that will copy a glob result into postgres. This is what I have:

`import psycopg2, glob`

`sitesizetemp = glob.glob('C:/Data/Sheltered BLPUs/CSVs/sitesize*.csv')`

`conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres")`

`cur = conn.cursor()`

`cur.execute("COPY sitesize FROM" sitesizetemp "DELIMITER ',' CSV;")`

`conn.commit()`

`cur.close()`

`conn.close()`

I'm pretty new to all of this so any help is very welcome! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import psycopg2, glob

sitesizetemp = glob.glob('C:/Data/Sheltered BLPUs/CSVs/sitesize*.csv')
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

for f in sitesizetemp:
    cur.execute("COPY sitesize FROM '%s' DELIMITER ',' CSV;" % f)

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```